# Is there a way to have multiple colours for selection glyphs in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a scatter plot where the points with a x-value < 50 are blue, and the points with a x-value > 50 are red. I'm attempting to have the colours invert when I select them with the box select tool. The selected colours that are blue should turn red and vice versa.

I tried to do this by giving an array of colours to the `fill_color` attribute of the `selection_glyph` property, but the property doesn't take an array. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Circle

N = 100
max = 100
x = np.random.random(size=N) * max
y = np.random.random(size=N) * max
output_file("scatter.html")

color1 = []
color2 = []
for a in x:
    if a > 50:
        color1.append("red")
        color2.append("blue")
    else:
        color1.append("blue")
        color2.append("red")

p = figure(tools = "box_select, tap", width = 400, height = 400, 
           x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))

circles = p.circle(x, y, size=10, fill_color = color1, line_color = None)
#circles.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = color2, line_color = None)
#circles.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = color1, line_color = None)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Split your data into two groups, plot each with their own call to `p.circle`, giving each call a different selection/nonselection policy:

```
p = figure(tools = "box_select, tap", width = 400, height = 400, 
           x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))

circles1 = p.circle(x1, y1, size=10, color="red", line_color=None)
circles1.selection_glyph    = Circle(fill_color="blue", line_color=None)
circles1.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_color="red",  line_color=None)

circles2 = p.circle(x2, y2, size=10, color="blue", line_color=None)
circles2.selection_glyph    = Circle(fill_color="blue", line_color=None)
circles2.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_color="red",  line_color=None)
```

As a bonus you don't have to send a long list of colors for every scatter point (in case you have a great many points).